# How to remove array items from string?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have this string: `This is my example #foo and #bar`

And this array: `['#foo','#bar']`

And this is the string I would like to have: `This is my example and`

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your string and array:

```
s = "This is my example #foo and #bar"
a = ['#foo', '#bar']
```

Then:

```
answer_array = (s.split(" ") - a).join(" ")
```

Gives the answer:

```
=> "This is my example and"
```

Comment: Thx, this works as intended and strips out all unwanted spaces!

Comment: This doesn't work if `s` contains two or more consecutive spaces or an element of `a` contains a leading or trailing space. For example, suppose `s` contains column headings: `s = "Name        Age        Ht        Wt"` and `a = ['        Age', '        Wt']`. Then `answer_array #=> "Name Age Ht Wt"`.

Answer (score 0):

The following preserves whitespace:

```
str = 'This    is my example   #foo and #bar'
arr = ['#foo','#bar']

r = Regexp.new arr.each_with_object('') { |s,str| str << s << '|' }[0..-2]
  #=> /#foo|#bar/
str.gsub(r,'')
  #=> "This    is my example and "
```

Another example (column labels):

```
str = "    Name        Age        Ht        Wt"
arr = ['        Age', '        Wt']

r = Regexp.new arr.each_with_object('') { |s,str| str << s << '|' }[0..-2]
  #=> /        Age|        Wt/
str.gsub(r,'')
  #=> "    Name        Ht"
```